# What is the process for generating a bare metal binary with MSVC tools?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, arm64, firmware, bare-metal

**What is the process for generating a bare metal binary with MSVC tools?**

In GNU land, you `cc` compile or `as` assemble the sources into object files, `ld` link the object files into an ELF (with a linker script) and then `objcopy` the relevant sections out of the ELF as a "firmware binary". I want to do the same thing, but only using MSVC provided tools.

I've been testing with the following ARM64 `startup.s`:

```
 AREA .text, CODE, READONLY
start
 LDR w1, =0xDEADBEEF
 B .
 END
```

This is suppose to simply load the lower 32 bits of the X1 register with 0xDEADBEEF and then spin. To assemble the code I run:

```
armasm64.exe startup.s
```

I'm guessing that if I had a `peripherals.c` source file, I'd need to link `startup.s` and `peripherals.c` into a single executable file (COFF?, PE?). Finally, I'd need to strip the any COFF/PE headers so that an ARM MCU can execute the code when loaded.

Comment: Do you want to be able to develop/compile under Windows, or do you really want to use the Microsoft arm64 assembler/linker ? Please note that there may be far less support available. For example, I tried to find out where to download armasm64.exe from in order to try answering your question, to no avail...

Comment: I really want to use the MSVC toolchain. I got armasm64.exe from "MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ ARM64 build tools (v14.28)" found in Individual Components feature install screen of VS2019.

I know that Microsoft now supports ARM and IoT devices so I figured that perhaps Visual Studio Build Tools should now be able to support bare metal development. I've spent quite a few hours attempting to coerce the MSVC toolchain to mimic what I know from my GNU experience but I've started thinking that perhaps a Windows Developer would have a better mindset for knowing if this is possible or not.

Comment: @Frant ... in regards to "Please note that there may be far less support available." ... that is why I'm leaning on SO. ;-)

Comment: no problem, just wanted to make sure what your requirements were.

Comment: I think I tried to use microsoft tools way back when the first arm support happened, it was a dead end at the time.  I didnt know as much at the time either.  Is this simply one of those climb the mountain because it is there punishments or is there a real goal/expectation?   LIkely better suited to a microsoft forum or directly with microsoft.

Comment: or does their object file fit within something that gnu ld accepts?  I assume you can make objects with msvc C or asm.  If it is a  linking problem and you cant get the linker directly nor the C compiler indirectly, then perhaps use or convert (should be straightforward to write your own tool) the objects and use gnu's linker for the link phase, just like clang/llvm often results in that path.

Comment: @old_timer: according to `binutils-2.35.1/bfd/config.bfd`, it seems there is currently no support whatsoever for the PE format and aarch64.

Comment: @Frant thus writing a conversion tool.

Comment: @old_timer: I was more answering to the `or does their object file fit within something that gnu ld accepts?` part or your comment: answer is no from what I understand. But yes, a conversion tool could be written I guess.

Comment: @Frant, ahh, peace....yeah, not surprised...(which is why I made my comment about make a tool)

Comment: @Vincent Agriesti: The linker does now allow specifying a base address below 4GiB. This is may be a hint that the MSVC aarch64 tools are designed to create executable files for a target supporting a general purpose operating system  with MMU support. This does not fit well IMHO with the "firmware binary" concept.

Comment: @old_timer: [pefile](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile) would likely be a good starting point for the tool you were mentioning, even though I am not a big fan of Python (I lost the Ruby/Python war). I have not been able to identify an equivalent to libelf` for the PE format yet, any hints ?

Comment: @Frant I would google the file format and simply read it.  Same with elf simply write it, elf is a pretty simple file format.  When I did this exact thing years ago microsoft output coff and this is what I did to find that their compiler wasnt any better if not worse than gcc (which is about average or was at the time and has not gotten much better, in some cases worse).  so I gave up using the microsoft tools at that point.  I dont use any libraries or tools other than binutils.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224998/discussion-between-frant-and-old-timer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* I am not within my area of expertise here, and I am proposing an answer based on some tests I did using the MSVC tools, after reading some Microsoft documentation, and three days after the question was asked with no answers having be proposed yet. I hope this  answer will trigger more informed answers, so that I may gladly retract it.

The answer to the question "What is the process for generating a bare metal binary with MSVC tools?" is likely: "There is none".

`aarch64-pe.asm`:

```
 AREA .text, CODE, READONLY
 EXPORT start
start
 LDR w1, =0xDEADBEEF
 B .
 END
```

(The symbol 'start' needs to be made public using the `EXPORT` directive in order to be resolved by the linker).

Assembling:

```
armasm64.exe aarch64-pe.asm
```

Now, the linker for aarch64 (version 14.28.29334.0) does for example only support a limited list of target subsystems:

```
BOOT_APPLICATION,
CONSOLE,
WINDOWS,
NATIVE,
POSIX,
EFI_APPLICATION, EFI_BOOT_SERVICE_DRIVER, EFI_ROM, EFI_RUNTIME_DRIVER
```

From the Microsoft and EFI documentation, it seems all those subsystems require a loader capable of understanding  the `PECOFF` format or to be able to run into the  `BCD WMI Provider` environment in the case of the `BOOT_APPLICATION` subsystem.

There is no such thing as a "BAREMETAL" subsystem.
When attempting to link aarch64-pe.obj for each of the subsystems but `EFI_ROM` using `0x0000000040000000` as the base address, the linker exited displaying the same error, complaining that the start address could not be less than 4GiB:

```
D:\opt\msvc\arm64>for %I in (BOOT_APPLICATION CONSOLE WINDOWS NATIVE POSIX EFI_APPLICATION EFI_BOOT_SERVICE_DRIVER EFI_ROM EFI_RUNTIME_DRIVER) do link /entry:start /BASE:0x0000000040000000 /subsystem:%I aarch64-pe.obj

D:\opt\msvc\arm64>link /entry:start /BASE:0x0000000040000000 /subsystem:BOOT_APPLICATION aarch64-pe.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29334.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1355: invalid base address 0x40000000; ARM64 image cannot have base address below 4GB

D:\opt\msvc\arm64>link /entry:start /BASE:0x0000000040000000 /subsystem:CONSOLE aarch64-pe.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29334.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1355: invalid base address 0x40000000; ARM64 image cannot have base address below 4GB

D:\opt\msvc\arm64>link /entry:start /BASE:0x0000000040000000 /subsystem:WINDOWS aarch64-pe.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29334.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1355: invalid base address 0x40000000; ARM64 image cannot have base address below 4GB

D:\opt\msvc\arm64>link /entry:start /BASE:0x0000000040000000 /subsystem:NATIVE aarch64-pe.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29334.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1355: invalid base address 0x40000000; ARM64 image cannot have base address below 4GB

D:\opt\msvc\arm64>link /entry:start /BASE:0x0000000040000000 /subsystem:POSIX aarch64-pe.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29334.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1355: invalid base address 0x40000000; ARM64 image cannot have base address below 4GB

D:\opt\msvc\arm64>link /entry:start /BASE:0x0000000040000000 /subsystem:EFI_APPLICATION aarch64-pe.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29334.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1355: invalid base address 0x40000000; ARM64 image cannot have base address below 4GB

D:\opt\msvc\arm64>link /entry:start /BASE:0x0000000040000000 /subsystem:EFI_BOOT_SERVICE_DRIVER aarch64-pe.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29334.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1355: invalid base address 0x40000000; ARM64 image cannot have base address below 4GB

D:\opt\msvc\arm64>link /entry:start /BASE:0x0000000040000000 /subsystem:EFI_ROM aarch64-pe.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29334.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/BASE' due to '/SUBSYSTEM:EFI_ROM' specification

D:\opt\msvc\arm64>link /entry:start /BASE:0x0000000040000000 /subsystem:EFI_RUNTIME_DRIVER aarch64-pe.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29334.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1355: invalid base address 0x40000000; ARM64 image cannot have base address below 4GB
```

This is likely an issue for a bare-metal embedded system, or may this require an MMU to be available and already configured by a ... bare-metal program starting with the MMU disabled from a start address less than 4GiB.

When running `dumpbin.exe` against aarch64-pe.efi, the base address seemed to be set to `0000000180000000` since the `ldr` instruction was located at `0x0000000180001000`, and the file type was set to `DLL`.

```
dumpbin.exe  /disasm aarch64-pe.efi
File Type: DLL

  0000000180001000: 18000041  ldr         w1,0000000180001008
  0000000180001004: 14000000  b           0000000180001004
  0000000180001008: DEADBEEF

  Summary

        1000 .rdata
        1000 .text
```

When executing `dumpbin.exe` against the executables produced by the linker with `0x0000000100000000` as the base address, the file type was consistantly `EXECUTABLE IMAGE`.

Even more, `dumpbin.exe` does not seem to offer converting the resulting executable into a standard format such as `s-record` or `intel hex` either.

My conclusion would therefore be that the MSVC tools **alone** do not allow building aarch64 bare-metal applications for the time beeing.

Comment: This is awesome info! Thanks for looking all this up. I'm looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/base-base-address?view=msvc-160 which states: "when the /DYNAMICBASE:NO option was set, the operating system first attempts to load a program at its specified ... address. If sufficient space is not available there, the system relocates the program. To prevent relocation, use the /FIXED option."

It's weird that it wont just let you override the base address.

Comment: When I get some time tonight I'll play with overriding the base address ... do you have a reference to where the 4GiB limit is documented? I'm going to make a Feature Request to VS Developer Community if there isn't a documented reason to not have this ability.

Comment: I don't have a reference, I just got the `ARM64 image cannot have base address below 4GB` error message every time I was using a base address less than 4GiB. And according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/base-base-address?view=msvc-160),  the default base address for a 64 bit executable is `0x140000000`.

Comment: Since `the operating system first attempts to load a program at its specified or default base address. If sufficient space is not available there, the system relocates the program. To prevent relocation, use the /FIXED option.`, this would IMHO confirm that the Microsoft tools are not suited for building bare-metal programs: that means the executable programs they produce do require a sophisticated loader with MMU support in order to be loaded. In the case you would agree or  get a confirmation, I would appreciate you accepting my answer since this may flag it as valid to other people.

Comment: I am beginning to agree. I was able to use the asmarm.exe (32bit) assembler to set the base address to 0x0 without error. Interestingly it'll still always have a VA offset of 0x1000 (4 KiB) bytes. I'm assuming this hard coded to prevent developers from referencing zero without a SEGFAULT. I suspect this is because there is an assumption that all code built with the MSVC assembler will be executed in a virtual address environment governed by an MMU. Shame ... I was really hoping for that magical "allow me to access physical memory" flag. Oh well. Thank you for all your effort!

Comment: Even without the tools assuming the executable will be loaded by a MMU-aware loader, I think Microsoft tools for creating a binary image or a file in s-record/Intel hex format from the resulting executable in `PE-COFF` format would still be missing. What do you think?

Comment: I agree there is no documented tool for the section/binary extraction. That said, The linker does have the ability to merge the sections, allowing us to merge all sections into ".text", following that it would be simple enough to write a shell script (e.g. cmd, pwsh) to parse out the binary ourselves with the output of dumpbin.exe.

Comment: Theoretically, the solution to the question AFAIK is to hand craft the IVT to jump to code assembled by the arm32 assembler @ address 0x1000 where we'd setup the MMU page tables. Following that you'd pivot to aarch64 mode, copy/map the aarch64 code into the 4GiB offset and branch, setup the CRT and then pivot into C land.  ... This is not unlike the typical behavior of mainstream OSes where they go for a least common denominator before negotiating up the stack to what we know as the modern OS "mode". (i.e. x86's legacy BIOS to real mode to protected mode to OS)

Comment: Bah ... these stackoverflow comments aren't doing it for me. If I can find the time, I'll write up something more substantial to describe my last comment in detail with examples. In any case, its not tenable for a real (modern) world situation IMHO. In any real world situation, folks are going to fall back to LLVM or MinGW.